# When I create a bootable USB device, does "Startup Disk Creator" use all the space on the device?

Tags: installation, usb

I want to put a bootable image of Ubuntu on my USB device.  I'm following the directions on ubuntu.com.  My USB device has 500Gb or something.  Does it have to use all of the space?  Or is there a way to only use 2 or 3Gb?

Comment: Just commenting (rather than answering) because this is only speculation, but you may be able to partition the drive and create the startup disk only on a single partition.

There's also a slider for setting "reserved extra space."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, it uses as much as it has to in order to make the device bootable but you can tell it to use more space so that you can store files on the desktop of the live session.

Comment: I tried it.  And he was right.